In .Net Core 2.1, can two authentication schemes exist together and be used by separate calls?
I've been working ITFoxTec SAML 2.0 library and I just found out that the services.AddSaml2(); call is basically this:
services.AddAuthentication(Saml2Constants.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(Saml2Constants.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = new PathString(loginPath);
        o.SlidingExpiration = slidingExpiration;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessDeniedPath))
        {
            o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(accessDeniedPath);
        }
        if (sessionStore != null)
        {
            o.SessionStore = sessionStore;
        }
        o.Cookie.SameSite = cookieSameSite;
        o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSecurePolicy;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieDomain))
        {
            o.Cookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
        }
    });

Which would explain why it always seem to override my existing Authentication, which is this:
   services.AddAuthentication(AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCookie(opts => {
           opts.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
           opts.SlidingExpiration = true;
           opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(21);
       });

I have 2 login buttons; one for SAML and one for my local cookie login.
I want them to work separately but the ITFoxTec services.AddSaml(); always seems to interfere with mine.
Is there a way to "chain" my existing cookie authentication into or after the ITFoxTec one?
Thanks!

If you register more than one authentication scheme, you should specify, which authentication scheme you want to use in every route handler (whole controller or exact api endpoint), for example
// Startup
services
.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(o => ... );

services.AddAuthentication("Custom").AddCookie(o => ... )

// Controllers 

  [Authorize(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
  public class FirstController{}

  [Authorize("Custom")]
  public class SecondController{}


The problem is that the ITFoxTec library seems to hijack my existing Cookie authentication....
